# Z3: Convert between FP and BitVector?

Tags: z3

Is there any way to convert between BitVector and FP in SMTLIB2, something like the int2bv and bv2int functions?

To clarify, I am looking for a raw representation of the bits, not e.g., a rounded integer in BitVec form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be precise, there is no standard for floating point arithmetic in SMTLIB yet. There is a draft for this which will be finalized at a later point in time; this draft does not contain such functions at the moment. However, Z3 does support such conversion functions when the `QF_FPABV` logic is enabled.

These functions are called

```
asIEEEBV (takes a float and returns a BV in IEEE764 format of appropriate size)
```

and

```
fromIEEEBV (takes a BV in IEEE764 format and returns a float of appropriate size)
```

Comment: Update on this one: The SMT theory for floating points has been finalized: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories/FloatingPoint.smt2 Z3 supports exactly those functions in the standard and all previous operators have been removed.

Comment: Link has changed, here is the updated location http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-FloatingPoint.shtml