# Bitvector arithmetics on Z3

Tags: z3, bitvector

I'm trying to use Z3 to solve arithmetic equations using bitvector arithmetic. I was wondering if there is a way to handle also Real numbers. For example if I can specify a constant different from #x1 and use real number instead.

```
(set-option :pp.bv-literals false)
(declare-const x (_ BitVec 4))
(declare-const y (_ BitVec 4))
(assert (= (bvadd x y) #x1))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both SMT-Lib (and Z3) fully support real numbers: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-Reals.shtml

You can simply write your example as follows:

```
(declare-const x Real)
(declare-const y Real)
(assert (= (+ x y) 1))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

You can also mix/match `Int`/`Real`/`Bitvector`, so long as everything is properly typed. Here's an example showing how to use Ints and Reals together:

```
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)
(declare-const c Int)
(declare-const d Real)
(declare-const e Real)
(assert (> e (+ (to_real (+ a b)) 2.0)))
(assert (= d (+ (to_real c) 0.5)))
(assert (> a b))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

However, note that conversion from bit-vectors to integers is usually uninterpreted. See here for a discussion: [Z3 int2bv operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30986454/z3-int2bv-operation/30996623#30996623)

Comment: Thank you for your response. What You've said is right, anyway with 'Real' I cannot use bitwise operations, but I must use bit vectors.

Comment: Mixing/matching of types are allowed too; so long as everything is properly typed. See the updated answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841212/z3-convert-between-fp-and-bitvector may be relevant.